# Multi column search in SQLITE

Tags: sqlite, search

I have to search a single string in multiple coloumn in SQLITE but I am unable to get the results, I am using the following query to do the search:

```
Select * 
From MyTable 
Where (col1 || '--' || col2) like '%abc xyz 123%'
```

Let's say I have **'abc'** in **col1** and **'xyz 123'** in **col2**.

Any help.

Comment: Try this: Select *from yourtable where col1 like 'searchstring' or col2 like 'searchstring' etc.\

Comment: Your query does the search but it will fail in above mentioned scenario.

Comment: How can you say it will fail. Did you try it.It wont Fail. You need to Pass different string for col. Select * From Yourtable where col1 like 'abc' or col2 like 'xyz 123'.

Comment: I don't want to separate both string and can I know which string is part of col1 or col2 as I have to search complete string for both coloumns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct answer is that I have to modify the above query a little bit like this,

```
Select * From MyTable Where (col1 || ' ' || col2) like '%abc xyz 123%'
```

Answer (score 1):

> Lets say I have 'abc' in col1 and 'xyz 123' in col2.

`col1 || '--' || col2` is equal `'abc--xyz 123'`, so will not match `'%abc xyz 123%'`!

You should use

```
 SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE col1 || ' ' || col2 LIKE '%abc xyz 123%'
```

or

```
 SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE col1 || '--' || col2 LIKE '%abc--xyz 123%'
```

Note: parenthesis are not needed as `||` has higher precedence than `LIKE`.

Answer (score 0):

The operands of your `LIKE` statement have to match criteria. If you are looking for a "single string" exact match from concatenation of the fields in those two columns and the (col1) field has 'abc' while the (col2) field has 'xyz 123' ...then the left-hand operand of your `LIKE` is the concatenation (col1 || col2) and the right-hand operand is the concatenation ('%abc%' || '%xyz 123%')
resulting in the statement:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE (col1 || col2) LIKE '%abc%'||'%xyz 123%';
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE (col1 || '--' || col2) LIKE '%abc%'||'--'||'%xyz 123%';
```

Example:

```
C:\SQLite3>sqlite3 test
    SQLite version 3.8.1 2013-10-17 12:57:35
    Enter ".help" for instructions
    Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
    sqlite> CREATE table MyTable (col1 text, col2 text);
    sqlite> INSERT into MyTable (col1, col2) values ('abc', 'xyz 123');
    sqlite> SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE (col1 || col2) LIKE '%abc xyz 123%';
    sqlite> SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE (col1 || col2) LIKE '%abc%' || 'xyz 123%';
    abc|xyz 123
    sqlite> SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE (col1 ||'--'|| col2) LIKE '%abc xyz 123%';
    sqlite> SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE (col1 ||'--'|| col2) LIKE '%abc%'||'--'||'%xyz 123%';
    abc|xyz 123
    sqlite>
```